# How do I update ASP Dropdown whose list item are added by jQuery AJAX call : Error Invalid postback or callback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a simple problem which I complicated. My web application has a ASP Dropdown whose values I wish to populate from the database. So I use jquery and Ajax to perform and dynamically add the list item to the dropdown which I am successful at. However as soon as I select a value and  hit the submit button I get the

```
Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

I realize the problem is that since server side is not aware of these newly added values it throws this error. I absolutely need the ASP dropdown and cannot use Select hence the only option I have is to use update Panel which  I am completely unfamiliar with. I gave it a shot but it didn't work and since last 3 hours I am stuck and cant move forward.

My AJAX Call looks like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "salesQuote.aspx/getLabelAndValue",
    data: "{fieldName: \"tier\"}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
         console.log("karan");
         $.each(msg.d, function () {
               $("#tier").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
         });
    },
    error: function () {                   
           alert("Failed to load names");
    }
});
```

The c# web service looks like

```
[WebMethod]
public static ArrayList getLabelAndValue(string fieldName)
{
    try
    {
        //.....database connection...
        ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            temp.Add(new ListItem(  (string)dr.GetValue(0), (string)dr.GetValue(1)) );
        }
        return temp;
        ....
}
```

The ASP dropdown with update panel looks like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
     <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:DropDownList  class="form-control" ID="tier" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="tierAccessChange" >
           </asp:DropDownList>
     </ContentTemplate>
     <triggers>
         <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="tier" eventname="SelectedIndexChanged" />
     </triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I don't know what to do next or what I have done is right. Please point me to the correct direction as to how do I get the selected value after hitting the submit button in the control of dropdown.

Edit 1: I tried adding in the web config. I got rid of the error but I couldnt get the selected value in the control after submitting

```
<system.web>
   <pages enableEventValidation="false"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Webforms have a tendency to make you do things their way. Instead of adding the option to the control on the client you could try posting the new value to the server and then adding the option to the dropdown in your server code. (Even if you add it from the client you'll probably want to add the new value server-side after you receive it. Otherwise it won't be persisted as an item in the list. It will just disappear.)

Also, how are you reading the value of the dropdown? ASP.NET might not recognize it as an option in the server control, but it's still getting posted when the form is submitted. You could read it directly from `Request.Form["YourDropDownClientId"].`